# How to make a model of 10000 Unique items using tensorflow? Will it scale?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have a use case where I have around 100 images each of 10000 unique items. I have 10 items with me which are all from the 10000 set and I know which 10 items too but only at the time of testing on live data. I have to now match the 10 items with their names. What would be an efficient way to recognise these items? I have full control of training environment background and the testing environment background. If I make one model of all 10000 items, will it scale? Or should I make 10000 different models and run the 10 items on the 10 models I have pretrained.

Comment: can you be more specific?
What models did you pretrain, what's the architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is regarding something called **"one-vs-all classification"** you can do a google search for that, the first hit is a video lecture by Andrew Ng that's almost certainly worth watching.

The question has been long studied and in a plethora of contexts. The answer to your question does very much depend on what model you use. But I'll assume that, if you're doing image classification, you are using convolutional neural networks, because, after all, they're state of the art for most such image classification tasks.

In the context of convolutional networks, there is something called **"Multi task learning"** that you should read up on. Boiled down to a single sentence, the concept is that the more you ask the network to learn the better it is at the individual tasks. So, in this case, you're almost certain to perform better training 1 model on 10,000 classes than 10,000 classes each performing a one-vs-all classification scheme.

Take for example the 1,000 class Imagenet dataset, and CIFAR-10's 10 class dataset. It has been demonstrated in numerous papers that first training against Imagenet's 1,000 class dataset, and then simply replacing the last layer with a 10 class output and re-training on CIFAR-10's dataset will produce a better result than just training on CIFAR-10's dataset alone. There are admittedly multiple reasons for this result, Imagenet is a larger dataset. But the richness of class labels, multi-task learning, in the Imagenet dataset is certainly among the reasons for this result.

So that was a long winded way of saying, use one model with 10,000 classes.

---

An aside:

If you want to get really, really interesting, and jump into the realm of research level thinking, you might consider a 1-hot vector of 10,000 classes rather sparse and start thinking about whether you could reduce the dimensionality of your output layer using an embedding. An embedding would be a dense vector, let's say size 100 as a good starting point. Now class labels turn into clusters of points in your 100 dimensional space. I bet your network will perform even better under these conditions.

If this little aside didn't make sense, it's completely safe to ignore it, your 10,000 class output is fine. But if it did peek your interest look up information on Word2Vec, and read this really nice post on how face recognition is achieved using embeddings: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78. You might also consider using an Auto Encoder to generate an embedding for the images (though I favor triplet embeddings as typically used in face recognition myself).